# Separate character variable into two columns

Tags: r

I have scraped some data from a url to analyse cycling results. Unfortunately the name column exists of the name and the name of the team in one field. I would like to extract these from each other. Here's the code (last part doesn't work)

```
#get url
stradebianchi_2020 <- read_html("https://www.procyclingstats.com/race/strade-bianche/2020/result")

#scrape table 
results_2020 <- stradebianchi_2020%>%
  html_nodes("td")%>%
  html_text()

#transpose scraped data into dataframe
results_stradebianchi_2020 <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(results_2020, 8, byrow = F)))

#rename
names(results_stradebianchi_2020) <- c("rank", "#", "name", "age", "team", "UCI point", "PCS points", "time")

#split rider from team

separate(data = results_stradebianchi_2020, col = name, into = c("left", "right"), sep = " ")
```

I think the best option is to get the team variable name and use that name to remove it from the 'name' column.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What library are you using for `read_html`.   There is more than one such function.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If we had a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then we wouldn't need to know where `read_html` comes from.  To answer your question, all we need is your input dataset (`dput(head(results_stradianchi_2020, 10))` for example.  `separate` is the right way to go, so your problem is either with the input data or the separate specification.

Comment: You could try `stringr::str_split_fixed(results_stradebianchi_2020$name, pattern=" ", n=2)` and `cbind` it to your dataset as two new variables.

Comment: Please include the necessary `library()` calls, so your example is reproducible.

Comment: I am using the rvest, tidyverse and dplyr libraries.

Comment: for the record, `rvest` calls `xml2` when loaded. So technically `read_html` comes from `xml2` not from `rvest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in base R with `gsub` and replace in the `name` column the pattern of `team` column with `""`, i.e. nothing. We use `apply()` with `MARGIN=1` to go through the data frame row by row. Finally we use `trimws` to clean from whitespace (where we change to `whitespace="[\\h\\v]"` for better matching the spaces).

```
res <- transform(results_stradebianchi_2020,
                 name=trimws(apply(results_stradebianchi_2020, 1, function(x) 
                   gsub(x["team"], "", x["name"])), whitespace="[\\h\\v]"))
head(res)
#   rank  X.                  name age                    team UCI.point PCS.points           time
# 1    1 201         van Aert Wout  25        Team Jumbo-Visma       300        200 4:58:564:58:56
# 2    2 234        Formolo Davide  27       UAE-Team Emirates       250        150       0:300:30
# 3    3  87 Schachmann Maximilian  26        BORA - hansgrohe       215        120       0:320:32
# 4    4 111       Bettiol Alberto  26          EF Pro Cycling       175        100       1:311:31
# 5    5  44        Fuglsang Jakob  35         Astana Pro Team       120         90       2:552:55
# 6    6   7         Štybar Zdenek  34 Deceuninck - Quick Step       115         80       3:593:59
```

Comment: wow, this works great although I'm not sure how the code solves this.

Comment: @LarsHeemskerk I've added some explanation, hoping to clarify a bit

Answer (score 2):

I think your request is wrongly formulated. You want to remove `team` from `name`.

That's how you should do it in my opinion:

```
results_stradebianchi_2020 %>% 
    mutate(name = stringr::str_remove(name, team))
```

Write this instead of your line with `separate`.

In this case `separate` is not an optimal solution for you because the separation character is not clearly defined.

Also, I would advise you to remove the initial blanks from `name` with `stringr::str_trim(name)`

Comment: Thanks for the reformulation and the solutions. unfortunately I get the following error message:

Problem with `mutate()` input `name`.
x no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"
ℹ Input `name` is `stringr::str_remove(name, team)`.
Backtrace:
  9. dplyr::mutate(., name = stringr::str_remove(name, team))
 11. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: I'm using R 4.0, you are in R 3.x. Inside `as.data.frame`, write: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`